# spring cloud gateway + eureka + microservice on heroku is putting the port in the url result is error 503 on request to microservice via gateway

Tags: heroku, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I have 3 services deployed to Heroku.

- Spring cloud Gateway
- Eureka
- a Microservice

The Gateway and the Microservice are registered in eureka.

GATEWAY application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: gateway.herokuapp.com
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostName}/
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka.herokuapp.com/eureka/
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: employeeModule
          uri: lb://MICROSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/employee/**
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: TRACE
```

EUREKA application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${EUREKA_HOSTNAME:localhost}
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/}
```

MICROSERVICE application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MICROSERVICE
server:
  port: ${PORT:8081}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: microservice.herokuapp.com
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostName}/
    home-page-url-path: https://${eureka.instance.hostName}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka.herokuapp.com/eureka/
```

I am getting the correct response, when i am calling directly `https://MICROSERVICEURL/employee/message`

when I am calling the gateway `https://GATEWAYURL/employee/message` it should ask eureka for the address of the microservice and then route the request to the microservice to get the response.

But instead of routing to `https://MICROSERVICEURL/employee/message` it routes to the eureka version with the random heroku port. e.g.: `https://MICROSERVICEURL:RANDOMHEROKUPORT/employee/message`. This leads to an error 503 because of a timeout.

Is there a way to tell the gateway to ignore the port number?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

GATEWAY Log

```
2020-08-18T19:59:56.683925+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-18 19:59:56.683 TRACE 4 --- [or-http-epoll-1] o.s.c.g.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter  : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://microservice.herokuapp.com:41632/employee/message
2020-08-18T20:00:26.673252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/employee/message" host=gateway.herokuapp.com request_id=236faa79-1d66-4e30-8c32-f879228d08db fwd="79.205.56.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: You have `server.port: ${PORT:8081}` in microservice. $PORT probably comes from heroku. If you want port 80 or 443 set that in `server.port`.

Comment: Why do you use eureka if you are using heroku? Heroku already provides a balancer for each service and you are already using the heroku dns for it. I would suggest you to drop eureka and use the dns name of services in apigateway

Comment: @spencergibb I now have tried to set server.port to 80, 443, just $PORT so it can bind via the Heroku variable. It still tries to connect via this heroku port and times out.
I edited my question and added an output of the gateway log.

Comment: @cool I have to use eureka because it is part of my university task to use eureka.
I don't have to use heroku, but I wanted to because the database implementation is much better than the universities database server.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. You need to leave `server.port` alone as that is the port the actual process is listening on. You need to set `eureka.instance.non-secure-port=80` or `eureka.instance.secure-port=443` as that is the port reported to eureka.

Comment: thanks that was the Problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was setting the secure and non secure port for the eureka instance in the appllication.yml

MICROSERVICE application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MICROSERVICE
server:
  port: ${PORT:8081}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: microservice.herokuapp.com
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostName}/
    home-page-url-path: https://${eureka.instance.hostName}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka.herokuapp.com/eureka/
      non-secure-port: 80
      secure-port: 443
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the non-secure port and make sure it is enabled in the application.properties or .yml

```
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=80
```

you could also run it on the secure port but then you can only run 1 service.

[My application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcV8X.png)